# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I stuck in this error, I want to subtract two date and get the difference as Days
I always receive the below  error

[image]

here is the dataframe info

[image]

Comment: Don't post links to images, post raw text of your code and errors. The error here is that a Series has a `.dt` attribute, DataFrames do not, you need to call `.dt` against a column not the dataframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have pd.MultiIndex column headers.  I can tell you have MultiIndex column headers by tuples in your column names from pd.DataFrame.info() results.

See this example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,999,(5,5))) #create a dataframe

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','B','C','D','E'],['max','min','max','min','max']]) 
#create multi index column headers

type(df['A'] - df['E'])
```

Output:

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

***Note*** The type of the return even though you are subtracting one column from another column.  You expected a pd.Series, but this is returning a dataframe.

You have a couple of options to solving this.

### Option 1 use [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
type((df['A'] - df['E']).squeeze())
pandas.core.series.Series
```

### Option 2 flatten your column headers before:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
type(df['A_max'] - df['E_max'])
```

Output:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Now, you can apply .dt datetime accessor to your series.  `type` is important to know the object you are working with.

Comment: thanks so so much , it works ... appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Well, as @EdChum said above, .dt is a pd.DataFrame attribute, not a pd.Series method. If you want to get the date difference, use the `apply()` pd.Dataframe method.